# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonErrorShapeMetadata.withExceptionUnmarshaller

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

Trying to call AWS secrets manager api to get the secret. But getting this error while deploying the jar. I have made sure dependencies are included in the jar.

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.647</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.647</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.647</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code snippet

```
      val client: AWSSecretsManager = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder
                            .standard()
                            .withRegion(region)
                            .build()
```

Error:

````
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.<clinit>(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:148)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.build(AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.build(AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)```
...
````

Comment: Can you post more of your error? What you posted as the error is just part of the stack trace and not an actual error message.

Comment: Rest of the stack trace is mostly the calls from my code. But the above lines are the actual error...

Comment: The above is a stack trace, there is not a lot to go on without an error message, exception type etc.

Comment: 19/10/10 00:29:32 ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonErrorShapeMetadata.withExceptionUnmarshaller(Lcom/amazonaws/transform/JsonErrorUnmarshaller;)Lcom/amazonaws/protocol/json/JsonErrorShapeMetadata;

Comment: @Shawn I think Kohei's response below is correct. Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Yes, it was a version issue and the platform I where I am trying to run has a lower version. Thanks.

Comment: @Shawn sweet. Out of curiosity, what platform was it? All the versioning should be handled by that pom.xml file and you'res was correct.

Comment: databricks @committedandroider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withExceptionUnmarshaller()` has been introduced in `com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonErrorShapeMetadata` since version 1.11.622:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/commit/c6bb2c8709aaff68ed732d9232630f4c40b07fcd#diff-536c803a93cb58597c2e0bfe71e2815d

and your `pom.xml` seems to be correct.

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.647</version>
    </dependency>
```

So your program may refer to anther old version of `aws-java-sdk-core.jar` when running.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped. In the platform where I was trying this has aws-java-sdk-core version lot lower than 1.11.647. After the downgraded to below 1.11.622 version, it worked.

Comment: I have set pom.xml to same dependency version for aws-java-sdk-core & aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager, but I still get the same error message 

og4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonClientMetadata com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonClientMetadata.withSupportsIon(boolean)'

Answer (score 1):

I have wasted a lot of time to get pass that error but still couldn't. Finally I used another sdk.
Instead of using com.amazonaws from ***aws-java-sdk-core***,I used ***software.amazon.awssdk*** and it worked-

> ```
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
>         <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
>         <version>2.14.7</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

And use code documented here - [GetSecretValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-secretsmanager-src-main-java-com-example-secrets-GetSecretValue.java.html)